# Knockout dynamic <select> options based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, lodash

I want to create `<select>` drop-down where options change depending on how two tables are matched in between, basically all unmatched `<select>` elements have the remaining values. I have problem that I don't know where to start.

This is how far I got [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/EqadQ/)

```
var vm = function () {

var listA = ko.observableArray([
    { toMatch: "abc123", name: "Andrew" }, 
    { toMatch: "abc456", name: "Andrew" }, 
    { toMatch: "abc789", name: "Andrew" }]);

var listB = ko.observableArray([
    { match: ko.observable("abc123"), surname: "Smith" }, 
    { match: ko.observable(""), surname: "Cruse" }, 
    { match: ko.observable(""), surname: "Domnic" }]);

var optionsList = ko.computed(function () {
    var tempArr = [];
    var tempArr_2 = [];
    _.each(listA(), function (item, key, list) {
        var matched = false;
        tempArr.push(item.toMatch);
        _.each(listB(), function (item_1, key_1, list_1) {
            if (matched == false && item.toMatch == item_1.match()) {
                matched = true;
                tempArr_2.push(item.toMatch);
            }
        })
    })
    console.log(_.difference(tempArr,tempArr_2))
    return _.difference(tempArr,tempArr_2);
});

return {
    listA: listA,
    listB: listB,
    optionsList: optionsList
}
```

}

Results are that all boxes have the same value.

Here's [a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/EqadQ/7/) I came up with.

Comment: Ive read this a few times, its not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: do you just wan to remove items from the list once they have been selected?

Comment: @Tanner yes i want to remove values that are selected

Comment: @Jamiec sorry, what I want to do is to allow to select only unmatched values, e.g. `abc456`,`abc789`

Comment: Here is a solution I came up with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/EqadQ/7/)

Comment: I looked at your post, comments and code, but I still have no clue what it is you are trying to achieve. Variable names such as listA and listB are not very helpful either.